# How to share a common bindings for different ScriptContext with Java ScriptEngine API?

Tags: java, java-8, nashorn, scriptengine

I am playing with Nashorn and the ScriptEngine API of java 8. I have a unique instance of ScriptEngine to execute several different scripts. I would like to remove some functions (e.g. print) for all scripts I will execute, but specify a specific binding binding for each script.

My problem is that I do not know if it is possible to make a kind of hierarchy with ScriptContext.

Here is an exemple of what I would do :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("nashorn");
    Bindings bindings = engine.getBindings(ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);
    bindings.remove("print");

    // script I will run
    String script1 = "print('Hello world')";
    String script2 = "print(person)";

    // define a different script context
    ScriptContext newContext = new SimpleScriptContext();
    Bindings engineScope = newContext.getBindings(ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);

    // set the variable to a different value in another scope
    engineScope.put("person", "toto");

    // evaluate script but in global context
    // should throw message because print is not declared in the context
    try {
        engine.eval(script1);
    } catch (ScriptException se) {
        System.out.println(se.getMessage()); // out : ReferenceError: "print" is not defined in <eval> at line number 1
    }

    // should throw message because print is not declared in the context
    engine.eval(script2, newContext); // out : toto
}
```

Here, the probeme is that when I execute `script2` I would like that print has been removed from the context.

Is there a clean way to do that ?